# <ul> height is 0 in this code, why? (it has to do with overflow:hidden)

Tags: html-lists

Please refer to the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
 border: 1px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/  /* Remove this comments */
    background: yellow;
}

li {
 border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block; /* what is this used for here? */
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know why list height is zero, even though there are list elements in it?

If you comment in **overflow:hidden** in the css, then the list gets a proper height other than zero. Can you tell the reason?

Comment: Post all relevant code here directly.

Comment: Specifically, a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (not a dump of all your code).

Answer (score 7):

The height of your `ul` is zero because you're floating your child elements which, in essence, removes them from the layout of the containing list.

If you also float your `ul`, you'll see that it contains your child `li` elements and the height sizes itself as I believe that you're looking for it to do.

There is some further context on how `float` impacts page flow [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), if you're curious.

Comment: when i added float:left to the list as well, it indeed got fixed.

Comment: But why overflow:hidden in the css also effects this, any ideas?

Comment: On that, I'm not certain.  Frankly, I'm surprised by it and have it on a list to poke into at a later point.